# Can i use Apple Push Notification without SSL

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

i have got a HTTP Server on Windows CE, but this might not support SSL,....

can i push from that server without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you don't need to support SSL as a *server* but you need to make outbound SSL connections to *Apple's* https servers. As far as I'm aware there are no non-SSL servers; SSL is used so that Apple can trust *you* as well as the other way round.

It sounds fairly odd to create APNS notifications directly from Windows CE though... what sort of device is this?

Answer (score 0):

SSL communications happen from your server to Apple's server and not the other way around. You don't need to have SSL installed in your HTTP Server. What you will need is the certificates from Apple Developer program so you can communicate with Apple. Also make sure that your server does not block specific ports for connecting to Apple's test and production environments.

Answer (score -1):

X509Certificate test = new X509Certificate();
old code 
just i am add 2

X509Certificate2 test = new X509Certificate2();